# Jmeter - Ignore sampler visibility into view result tree - GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, i need to use Dummy sampler.

[image]

Is it possible somehow to be hidden this sampler into the view result tree listener?

[image]

Is it possible somehow to be hidden this sampler into the view result tree listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add: JSR223 PostProcessor

prev.setIgnore();